# Compare text within two images, but regardless of color

Tags: c#, image, compare, ocr

I want to compare two images.
On both images you can see a digit. For example: (img1: "5" img2: "5") img1 is a pure black digit. But img2 could be in various colors. The background is white. It doesn't matter what color is on img2, if there is a "5", it has to be matched.

How do I compare these images? It has to be a fast method.

Any clues?

Comment: Well, just a guess, what about maximize contrast and make picutures black and white and than compare?

Comment: In the same font? In the same position? Or are you asking for something more complicated e.g. computer vision, captcha breaking?

Comment: In LOLCode you can do `CAN HAZ CAPTCHAHACKER, KTHXBYE`.

Comment: How stringent are the requirements on the second image? Must the number always have the same, font, size, position, or could any of these variables deviate?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the background is always white, you could process the two images and whenever a pixel is not white, set it's color to black - essentially converting both images into black & white bitmaps.

Then you could compare the bitmaps. I'm assuming you have that part already covered. Otherwise, if the two images are supposed to be exact matches then you would go and compare each pixel to the other image for an exact match. If a pixel doesn't match.. they are not the same.  But this is very naive.. much better image recognition methods exist.